# google cloud and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-storage

I have just started playing with Google cloud. I used to work on normal servers so I need advice.
I created my first instance and deployed Wordpress. I installed woocommerce plugin. The shop is quite fast and I am happy (with the lowest settings) but now:

1. I wanted edit function.php but I can't. The attributes are read only so How can I change it?
2. How to get access to my all files I can't see them in storage cloud. How to set up ftp?
3. What about database for my shop? I understand I can create new data base but where to access to current data base of my wordpress.
4. What should I deploy more to work comfortable with my wordpress?
5. About ssl

> SNI SSL certificate slots are offered for no additional charge for
>   accounts that have billing activated. Free accounts are limited to 5
>   certificates.

I have no experience with ssl but I plan run shop so what it means. Free certificates for 5 instances or 5 deployement ? How many certificates do I need to run one shop?

I know there are many questions but I wanted to go further and all advise on internet is outdated because are for older versions of google cloud. Please help me to understand this all.

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the box?

Comment: it is a "normal" server. If you want to set up ftp, SSH to the box and set it up. You are asking too many questions at once. Each of your points should be a separate question, apart from 4 and 5 which are totally OT for stack.

Comment: Google App Engine is not a "normal" server. There is no writable filesystem (unless you like juggling with the GAE API), there's no SSH access, no FTP access and so on. Google Compute Engine on the other hand is a "traditional" VPS which has those options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're attempting to use WordPress on Google App Engine.

1. GAE has no real filesystem, so you cannot write to it (unless you juggle with the API GAE offers). Editing happens locally using the GAE SDK development server and you deploy your changes to the App Engine ecosystem using the SDK interface (GUI or CLI). All application writes should go to Google Cloud Storage (which is similar to Amazon S3 and the like).
2. I'm not certain whether the Google Cloud Storage can be accessed via traditional FTP. There might be some middleware required. You can see and browse the contents of your buckets in the developer project console (https://console.developers.google.com/).
3. The databases are on a separate "server" when using GAE. MySQL instances are spawned into the Google Cloud SQL ecosystem, which are available for App Engine and Compute Engine instances (and why not other places too). You can define the GCSQL address and port to `wp-config.php` like normally. You need to create a local MySQL database for your local installation. More: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/
4. When working with Google App Engine you should deploy the whole WordPress installation (`wp-config.php`, `wp-includes/`, `wp-admin/`, `wp-content/`, etc.) in order for it to work in the GAE system. For a "better" deployment system you should do some searching or ask a new question dedicated for that issue.
5. The certificates themselves on GAE are not free, but the "slots" you put the certificates into are. Free projects (no billing enabled) offer 5 free slots where you can put your purchased certificates. SSL SNI means that you can use multiple different domain/host certificates under a single listening IP address (which some years back was not that simple to do). What this all means that GCP offers a way to use certificates with their services, but you still need to get the certificates themselves elsewhere.

Have you seen the GAE starter project offered by Google: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/ ? It makes your live a bit easier when developing WP sites for Google App Engine.

**If** you're working with Google Compute Engine instances, then they should operate just like regular VPS machines, with some Google restrictions applied. I have not used them so I do not know the specifics.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to learn much more than I thought so for now I have to stay with my traditional servers. The costs looks higher as well.

Comment: The costs on GAE might actually become less than with traditional servers, but for small sites and applications there might be no or little difference. Additionally the work that goes into configuring and upkeeping a GAE app might be higher at first, but that is a workflow question.

Comment: Thank you for Your comments. I still test it and I think this will be the next thing I want to learn